# Word "that" after adverbial clause

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbial-phrases

May I put the word "that" after the adverbial clause and not right after the object "defects"?

> "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects on the electrical installation in the area **that** may represent a risk ..."

How to make clear that the word "that" specifies the object "defects" and not "area"? And please, correct me, if I use incorrect terminology.

Comment: To my mind it would be "perverse" to interpret the version as given above to mean the inspection is only concerned with finding defects ***in that specific area*** - which must have been previously identified as the (only) area that represents a risk. Syntactically you could validly move ***that*** to be immediately after ***defects***, but I think that would be rather "unusual". And to be honest, I wouldn't say it was particularly perverse to interpret that as implying the defects are only a risk *if they occur in that specific area* (which presumably isn't the intended sense).

Comment: You could move "that may represent a risk" to be right after "defects", so it reads "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects that may represent a risk in the electrical installation in the area..." but really I think it's pretty clear as it is.  It is unlikely someone would read it and think that the area represents a risk.

Comment: @stangdon: That's certainly a good way of removing any *possible* "ambiguity", but it does seem to be solving a problem that doesn't really exist. As you say, we'd probably all agree the same "likely meaning" for several variant phrasings that *could in principle* mean something significantly different. But I suggest that if a writer truly *did* intend one of those more "unexpected" meanings, he'd need to make some far more dramatic changes to have a reasonable chance of getting his message across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

> "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects on the electrical installation in the area, that may represent a risk..."

Adding the comma will create a pause, separating the words *area* and *that*. Compare this to "identify defects on the electrical installation, in the area that may represent a risk..."

> "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects on the electrical installation that may represent a risk..."

Remove the confusion by taking out *in the area*. This, however, does remove a detail which may be important in the context that you are using it in.

EDIT:

> "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects, on the electrical installation in the area, that may represent a risk..."

This is also grammatically correct. In this instance, *on the electrical installation in the area* is inserted into the sentence "The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects that may represent a risk..." as a piece of additional information. This makes it obvious that it is the defects that represent a risk, since "defects" and "risk" are in the same clause.

Comment: And what about putting comma after "defects" and "area" as well?

Comment: @McFly that is also correct. Added to answer

Comment: Neither of these seem particularly correct. That when used as a relative pronoun is always restrictive and thus not used with commas. I've likewise never seen separating a non-introductory prepositional phrase with commas.

Comment: Without the commas the relative pronoun "that" would apply to the electrical installation in the area, which is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of the inspection is to identify defects on the electrical installation in the area that may represent a risk ...

OP asks:

*How to make clear that the word "that" specifies the object "defects" and not "area"? And please, correct me, if I use incorrect terminology.*

What you wish to make clear is that the clause **that may represent a risk** modifies **defects**.

The solution is simple and does not rely upon punctuation but upon syntax alone:

> The purpose of the inspection is to identify in the electrical installation  defects that represent a risk.

We are able to reposition the adjunct phrase **in the electrical installation** so that it does not stand between **defects** and the clause modifying that noun.